# Angular Material Spinner doesn't render

Tags: angular, angular-cli, angular-material2

I am trying to create a app using Angular Material, even the documentation is pretty much ok, but there is no much help otherwise. I am using Angular4 and Angular-cli. So I installed and just created a simple spinner tag like this:

```
<div class="text-center">
  <img src="assets/Capture13.PNG" alt="" class="toplogo">
</div>

<div class="text-center">
    <mat-spinner> </mat-spinner>
</div>

<div>
    <input type="button" class="close" (click)="login('user','pwd')" value="hello" >
</div>
```

It didn't render anything. Shows a blank window

[image: The window with nothing]

I thought there is some issue with installation, but then I went to inspect the page and saw the following: 
[image: the spinner spinning]

When I hovered my mouse over the controls, it clearly shows I have a shape which is rotating exactly similar to a spinner. It makes me believe that the components is loading, but it is not just visible for some reasons. I installed Hammerjs too as recommended in documentation, and included the hammerjs, and prebuilt pink theme in my index.html too:

```
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/hammer.js/2.0.8/hammer.min.js"></script>

<link href="../node_modules/@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/indigo-pink.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

Anyone has any idea, what I might be missing. On top of it, I am not getting any error that it is not rendering etc because it seems that it does render. Any help please?

Comment: Strange, it works well on plunker: https://embed.plnkr.co/ibVGU6/ with (hammerjs)

Comment: indeed it does, that is why i am in a dizzy mode. because the same code works well with plunker.

Comment: The problem comes from your pink-theme I think because if I remove it from the plunker, I have the same problem. So you can try to add in your style.css @import "~@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/indigo-pink.css";

Comment: yep, thanks. That was the problem. It is solved.

Comment: ok, I so I answer your question.

Comment: yep you did. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem comes from your pink-theme I think because if I remove it from the [plunker](http://embed.plnkr.co/ibVGU6), I have the same problem. So you can try to add in your style.css

```
@import "~@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/indigo-pink.css"
```